# Bokeh: How to fix x-axis in time

Tags: datetime, axis, bokeh

I have produced a time series scatter plot in bokeh, which updates when a user interactively selects a new time series. However, I want to fix the x-axis between 0000 to 2359 hours for comparison (Bokeh tries to guess the appropriate x-range).

Below is a random snippet of data. In this code, how do I fix the x_range without it changing the scale to microseconds?

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import push_notebook, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import Range1d
output_notebook()

data = {'2015-08-20 13:39:46': [-0.02813796,  0],
 '2015-08-28 12:6:5': [ 1.32426938,  1],
 '2015-08-28 13:42:59': [-0.16289655,  1],
 '2015-12-14 16:19:44': [ 2.30476287,  1],
 '2016-02-01 17:8:32': [ 0.41165004,  0],
 '2016-02-09 11:26:33': [-0.65023149,  0],
 '2016-04-08 17:57:47': [ 0.09335096,  1],
 '2016-04-27 19:2:15': [ 1.43917208,  0]}

test = pd.DataFrame(data=data).T
test.columns = ["activity","objectID"]
test.index = pd.to_datetime(test.index)

p = figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=250, x_axis_label='X',    y_axis_label='Y', x_axis_type="datetime")# x_range = Range1d(# dont know what to put here))
r = p.circle(x=test.index.time, y=test["activity"])
show(p, notebook_handle=True);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a (scrappy) solution for this but it doesn't fix the axes sizes entirely since the size of the axes seems to be dependent on other axes properties such as the length of the y-tick labels.

```
# a method for setting constant x-axis in hours for bokeh:

day_x_axis = pd.DataFrame(data=[0,0], index=['2015-07-28 23:59:00', '2015-08-    28 00:01:00'], columns=["activity"]) 
day_x_axis.index = pd.to_datetime(day_x_axis.index)
new_time_series = pd.concat((old_time_series, day_x_axis), axis=0) # this will set all other columns you had to NaN.
```

I fixed my axes entirely by also setting the y_range property when instantiating the figure object.